# Modal in PHP with php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to use modal in PHP with the include function but there is an error with the header.php file I guess.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what is inside the header.php file:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

The error is the css file and js file cant process.
But when I do this, it's working :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Darren the css file and js file is now working. it cant read the files

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied much code ... at all, but straight off the bat, your modal won't open because you haven't specified any triggers on your `<button>`. Change it to:

```
<button id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Best to read up on [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) to understand how you need to trigger them.

---

If your files are not being included properly from the external CDN, check your Developers Console for any errors being shown/files being prevented from loading.

Comment: can you please check my edited post? because when i dont use include'header.php' it's working

Comment: @Adi alright - what file format is the modal? If it's `.html` it won't work. It needs to be `.php`. Also, try that and check the console, from there can you post errors if there are any